# How can I choose default checkbox at a certain value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

There is a list of values with checkbox.
How Can I choose default checkbox "true" at value "test1"?

```js
const Block_comp = ({ name, block_obj, change_chkbox}) => {
  const clear_name = name.replace(/^(\d+_|\\)(.*)$/g, '$2')
  return (
    <div className="str_strip_process w3-twothird w3-padding-small">
      <div className="w3-half">
        <label htmlFor={`${name}_id`}>
          <div className="w3-col l9 m9 s9 w3-right" title={clear_name}>
            {clear_name}
          </div>
        </label>
        <input
          id={`${name}_id`}
          className="w3-left w3-check"
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={change_chkbox}
          checked={block_obj.get('selected')}
          value={name}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: what is block_obj in the props?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is part of a **form** component, you can structure it like this:

here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-js-checkbox-example?file=src/App.js

```
// a checkbox component - basic isChecked & onChange props
// onChange will receive the checked value from the input change event
const Checkbox = ({ name, isChecked, onChange}) => {
    const clear_name = name.replace(/^(\d+_|\\)(.*)$/g, '$2');
    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor={`${name}_id`}>{clear_name}</label>
            <input
                id={`${name}_id`}
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isChecked}
                onChange={e => onChange(e.target.checked)}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

const Form = () => {
    // we create state for each field - can be done in different ways
    const [foo, setFoo] = useState(false);
    // we pass each state its initial value - bar is checked by default
    const [bar, setBar] = useState(true);
    const [bla, setBla] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <Checkbox name="foo" isChecked={foo} onChange={setFoo} />
            <Checkbox name="bar" isChecked={bar} onChange={setBar} />
            <Checkbox name="bla" isChecked={bla} onChange={setBla} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... if it is just to set a checkbox to be ticked by default, then:

```js
const Block_comp = ({ name, block_obj, change_chkbox}) => {
  const clear_name = name.replace(/^(\d+_|\\)(.*)$/g, '$2')
  return (
    <div className="str_strip_process w3-twothird w3-padding-small">
      <div className="w3-half">
        <label htmlFor={`${name}_id`}>
          <div className="w3-col l9 m9 s9 w3-right" title={clear_name}>
            {clear_name}
          </div>
        </label>
        <input
          id={`${name}_id`}
          className="w3-left w3-check"
          type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={true}
          onChange={change_chkbox}
          checked={block_obj.get('selected')}
          value={name}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with the ternary operator and default checked.

```
const Block_comp = ({ name, block_obj, change_chkbox}) => {
  const clear_name = name.replace(/^(\d+_|\\)(.*)$/g, '$2')
  return (
    <div className="str_strip_process w3-twothird w3-padding-small">
      <div className="w3-half">
        <label htmlFor={`${name}_id`}>
          <div className="w3-col l9 m9 s9 w3-right" title={clear_name}>
            {clear_name}
          </div>
        </label>
        <input
          id={`${name}_id`}
          className="w3-left w3-check"
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={change_chkbox}
          defaultChecked={{block_obj.get('selected')==="test1"?true:false}}
          checked={block_obj.get('selected')=== name?true:false}
          value={name}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```